# surface pro 3 with ubuntu enable advanced startup

Tags: boot, bios, surface

So I have successfully installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my Surface Pro 3. Now I am trying to install Kali Linux instead (since it is a secondary laptop). The problem is that it won't boot from USB anymore and I can't access the BIOS because there's a password on it which I do not know.
Only way is the activation of advanced startup which is in the Windows settings, but I erased Windows completely.

Does anyone know how could I enable advanced startup inside from Ubuntu?
Or any other idea? Battery removal is last resort.

Comment: I don't know about windows advanced settings stuff but this could totally work if you don't have a bootloader password. https://askubuntu.com/questions/500295/booting-ubuntu-iso-file-from-grub- menu I don't think we can get to this advanced startup in windows settings in ubuntu.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-advanced-startup-options-in-windows-10-or-8-2626229
Yeah this is how to do it on Windows. I was wondering if someone knows an alternative for Ubuntu.